# schedule chkdsk on all drives output results to file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wish to run a schedule `chkdsk` on all drives from a bat file via my task scheduler, that will force an automatic reboot where necessary and output the results for each drive to a text file.

I've been following an example listed here http://www.sharkyforums.com/showthread.php?302556-Automating-CHKDSK-F-R-on-all-Drives that looks to do what I need it to but it doesn't seem to be working.

in the `DriveLtr.txt` file I have my drives listed as

```
C:
D:
E:
```

Can anyone suggest a possible fix to get this up and running?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a barebones version (slightly modified) of the script in the link you posted.

```
for /f %%a in (DriveLtr.txt) do (
echo Y| CHKDSK %%a /F /R >>CheckDiskRpt.txt
)
```

You can add all the extra logging stuff you want to it, but that will loop over all the drives in the text file and run the `chkdsk` command for each of them, logging stdout to `CheckDiskRpt.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

@ECHO OFF

REM This is a script which will run a CHKDSK against drives specified between ()

FOR %%X IN (C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,...,Z) DO (CHKDSK %%X: > "C:\CHKDSK_LOGS\DRIVE_%%X_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.txt")